# create hidden field in code behind access to hidden field value

Tags: c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

I want to create a hidden html field:

```
string _ResultHidden = "";

var Detail_Like = MainClass.objFestivalImageLike.FestivalImageLike_List(MD.User_ID);

foreach (var item in Detail_Like)
{

    if (item.Festival_Image_Like_Count == 1)
    {
        _ResultHidden += **@"<asp:HiddenField ID=""hid_" + item.Festival_Image_ID + @""" runat=""server"" Value=""1""></asp:HiddenField>"**;
    }
    else
    {
         _ResultHidden += @"<asp:HiddenField ID=""hid_" + item.Festival_Image_ID + @""" runat=""server"" Value=""0""></asp:HiddenField>";
    }
}

Literal.Text = _ResultHidden;
```

Now I want access to the hidden field value.

Comment: i am testing: "hid_" + item.Festival_Image_ID.Value  not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create any control from code behind, and add it to page or panel control.
for hidden field you can do like this

**Code behind:**

```
  HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
  hf.ID = "myNEwHF";
  hf.Value = "myValue";
  Panel2.Controls.Add(hf); // or Page.Form.Controls.Add(hf);
```

**Html Markup:**

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
```